# pg_advisory_lock works but not pg_try_advisory_lock

Tags: java, postgresql, locking

I want to run a cron job from inside my application. But when I run multiple instance of this application, I wish to have mutual exclusion. i.e. the cron jobs are run only through a single process.

I am using ***advisory locks*** to achieve this.

When I tried using advisory locks. This is what I noticed.

I created dedicated table for this. For example a table called 'cron'. When I try

```
SELECT pg_advisory_lock(123) FROM cron;
```

It doesn't acquire any lock. But When I inserted a row into this table and tried the same command again, then acquiring lock is successful.
So my question: is it necessary to have at least a row to get advisory lock? Or am I missing something here?

Secondly When I went through the documentaion, I found that instead of `pg_advisory_lock` I can also use `pg_try_advisory_lock` which would return true or false (unlike `pg_advisory_lock` which throws an exception).

But when I tried pg_try_advisory_lock what I observed is, when one process executes and gets the lock. I see three entries created in pg_locks with lock_type *relation*, *virtualxid*, and *advisory*) When another process runs in parallel and tries to get lock, it created two more entries in pg_locks with lock_type as *relation* and *virtualxid*. And hence the second process also return true.

**With pg_try_advisory_lock both the process returns true.**

But If I use pg_advisory_lock and use lock_timeout(with very low value) , then the second process exits with exception. This way I could achieve mutual exclusion.

**So why is it not working with pg_try_advisory_lock but works with pg_advisory_lock (in conjunction with lock timeout)?**

Any hint is much appreciated

I am using Postgresql. And connecting via a Java Application.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a table to execute a function. Use just

```
SELECT pg_advisory_lock(123);
```

Note that if you use a table (like in the question) the function is executed as many times as the number of rows in the table. If the table is empty, the function is not executed at all.

The function `pg_try_advisory_lock()` just returns boolean. It cannot automatically abort the current transaction. You should check what the function returns and take some action depending on the result.

---

Update. The method `lockTable()` in your code always returns true.

```
private static boolean lockTable(Connection connection, LocalDateTime now) throws SQLException {
    String sqlQuery = String.format(GET_LOCK, now.getDayOfYear());
    try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery)) {
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            return rs.next();
            // obviously, this always returns true
            // instead you should do something like
            // return rs.getBool("pg_try_advisory_lock")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I understand about the table. It works even without any table. But with pg_try_advisory_lock, I understand it returns a boolean. But according to the documentation, it should return immediately with true (when lock is acquired) and false(when lock not acquired). But what I have observed is the second process doesn't return immediately when it cannot acquire lock. Rather it waits for the lock to be released by the first process and acquires the lock. This defeats the purpose and contradicts what is there in documentation

Comment: `pg_try_advisory_lock()` **always** returns immediately with `true` or `false`. Your observations are false but I really don't know what kind of mistake you have made. Do both processes use exactly the same function?

Comment: I have a standalone java program which connects to database and then tries to get lock. I am running the same program twice.

Comment: The scenario is simple. The program executes `select pg_try_advisory_lock(123);` and checks the result. If it is `false` then the program terminates, else it should proceed.

Comment: I am sorry my observation is a bit wrong. Actually `select pg_try_advisory_lock(123)` returns immediately in both the process, but it returns true in both. Edited my question

Comment: It's because you close the connection too soon. The session should last until the program does all it should. Insert a long pause into the app for testing.